# Print PDF programmatically - C# WinForms

Tags: winforms, pdf, printing, migradoc, printer-control-language

I need to print a SSRS report in PDF format from a WinForms application written in C#. The report is a PDF document (containing text, images & tables), in a byte array - and I don't want to save it to disk for security/performance reasons. The requirements for printing are that it needs to be done:
- in the fastest way possible
- with no user interaction 
- without the need to install anything on the client machine (we can't rely on any Adobe products being installed)
- third-party libraries can be used, as long as they can be installed together with the application

I came to 2 potential solutions: 
1. using MigraDoc - but I can't find a way to load and print an existing file, only a newly created PDF file, or one already saved to disk
2. sending the PDF directly to the printer, using "PDF Direct Print"/PCL/etc. This seems to be the fastest option, but I haven't implemented it yet, and it seems to not be supported by all printers.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to implement the options above, or any other options which meet the requirements?

Comment: I'm not aware of any framework, or otherwise generic, solution to your problem.  You will need a 3rd party tool of some sort, of which there are many options.  Recommending tools/libraries is off-scope for SO, but Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

MigraDoc cannot print PDF files, so one of your potential solutions is void.

Comment: OK, this clarifies one option. Thank you!